# Is it possible to sort nested documents in ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

Lets say I have the following mapping:

```
"site": {
  "properties": {
    "title":       { "type": "string" },
    "description": { "type": "string" },
    "category":    { "type": "string" },
    "tags":        { "type": "array" },
    "point":       { "type": "geo_point" }
    "localities":  { 
      type: 'nested',
      properties: {
        "title":       { "type": "string" },
        "description": { "type": "string" },
        "point":       { "type": "geo_point" }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm then doing an "_geo_distance" sort on the parent document and am able to sort the documents on "site.point". However I would also like the nested localities to be sorted by "_geo_distance", inside the parent document.

Is this possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unfortunately, no (at least not yet).

A query in ElasticSearch just identifies which documents match the query, and how well they match.

To understand what nested documents are useful for, consider this example:

```
{
    "title":    "My post",
    "body":     "Text in my body...",
    "followers": [
        {
            "name":     "Joe",
            "status":   "active"
        },
        {
            "name":     "Mary",
            "status":   "pending"
        },
    ]
}
```

The above JSON, once indexed in ES, is functionally equivalent to the following. Note how the `followers` field has been flattened:

```
{
    "title":            "My post",
    "body":             "Text in my body...",
    "followers.name":   ["Joe","Mary"],
    "followers.status": ["active","pending"]
}
```

A search for: `followers with status == active and name == Mary` would match this document... incorrectly.

Nested fields allow us to work around this limitation.  If the `followers` field is declared to be of type `nested` instead of type `object` then its contents are created as a separate (invisible) sub-document internally.  That means that we can use a [nested query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/nested-query.html) or [nested filter](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/nested-filter.html) to query these nested documents as individual docs.

However, the output from the nested query/filter clauses only tells us if the main doc matches, and how well it matches. It doesn't even tell us which of the nested docs matched. To figure that out, we'd have to write code in our application to check each of the nested docs against our search criteria.

There are a few [open issues](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/issues/search?q=nested&state=open&assignee=) requesting the addition of these features, but it is not an easy problem to solve.

The only way to achieve what you want is to index your sub-docs as separate documents, and to query and sort them independently.  It may be useful to establish a parent-child relationship between the main doc and these separate sub-docs.  (see [parent-type mapping](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/mapping/parent-field.html),  the Parent & Child section of the [index api docs](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/index_.html), and the  [top-children](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/top-children-query.html) and [has-child](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/has-child-query.html) queries.

Also, an ES user has mailed the list about a new [`has_parent` filter](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/issues/792) that they are currently working on in a [fork](https://github.com/hlian/elasticsearch/branches/has_parent). However, this is not available in the main ES repo yet.

Comment: Ok so I've played a bit with this. There's actually no way to search by the localities parent fields as I see it? You'd then have to include the parent field's that needs to be searchable in every child, right?

Comment: Correct.  You can't do joins.  Each document is evaluated on its own merits.  The parent/child and nested queries do double the work because they first run a query on (eg) the children, then use those values to run a query against the parents

Comment: Ok, so it's not possible to query on the children and also return the parent? Can you search on children and also query on the parent's fields?

Comment: I've posted a more extensive [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9637216/advice-on-elasticsearch-parent-child-mapping-quering) explaining what I'm trying to achieve