# Complex querying on Parent/Child documents with ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Considering this record structure

```
"place": {
  "id": "4f58e38866eaa71e74000027",
  "name": "Some name",
  "point" [14.53535, 56.32535],
  "hostname": "Something",
  "locality": "something",
  "type": "Some type",
  "average_price": 67
}

"container": {
  "title": "Something",
  "category": "Something"
}

"row": {
  "name": "Something",
  "description": "Something",
  "price": 45,
  "markings_array": ['some_tag', 'some_tag'],
  "prioritized": true
}
```

I'm trying to achieve this:

- Sort by alphabetic order on place.name
- Sort by distance on place.point
- Sort/Boost places by array of id's
- Boost places closest to given param point
- Boost rows if they are priotized
- Randomize sort on place.name
- Sort by place.average_price
- Term query on place.hostname and place.locality
- String query on row.name
- Facet on container.title
- Facet on row.markings_array

The results should in the end be used in this format, the 'central object' being the container:
EDIT: The 'central object' could also be the place.

```
[{
  "_score" : 183.96391,
  "container": {
    "title": "something",
    "category": "something",
    "place": {
      "id": "4f58e38866eaa71e74000027"
      "name": "Some name",
      "point" [14.53535, 56.32535],
      "hostname": "Something",
      "locality": "something",
      "type": "Some type" 
    },
    "rows": [
      {
        "_score": 183.96391,
        "name": "Something",
        "description": "Something"
        "price": 45,
        "markings_array" ['some_tag', 'some_tag']
      },
      {
        "_score": 133.96391,
        "name": "Something",
        "description": "Something"
        "price": 45,
        "markings_array" ['some_tag', 'some_tag']
      },
      {
        "_score": 123.96391,
        "name": "Something",
        "description": "Something"
        "price": 45,
        "markings_array" ['some_tag', 'some_tag']
      }
    ]
  }
}]
```

The rows should be ordered by their score.
How can this query be performed?

What I do right now is to index all fields on every row and then perform the search against the index holding the rows.

To get the desired output I would have to loop trough the results and group them by parent etc. The problem is that I also need scoring on place or container since I will present the container with place and rows in a list.

Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Did you ever found a satisfying solution? I posted a prety similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13974277/modeling-parent-child-relationships-product-productvariant-in-elasticsearch