# Modeling parent/child relationships (product/productvariant) in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Breaking my head on modeling productvariants using ES (or Solr for that matter)

Consider (contrived example):

- different products (say T-shirts)
- each product has a set of properties (productid, name, desc, brand, color, popularity)
- each product has a set of productvariants with properties (productvariantid (combi of productid++size), productid, size, availability, price)

This seems to be a standard parent/child relationship between product and productvariant. So I'd like to model it like that in ES.

I'd like to be able to do the following:

- A. Query for productvariants (and return all properties). No need to return product-properties, productvariant properties are enough.
- B. Each user-query is constrained  so that at most 1 productvariant matches per product (in the above example that means we constrain on productvariant.size)
- C. filter on price.
- D. filter on some properties of product
- E. order on price
- F. order on property of product such as popularity, or a combination of the 2.
- G. facet on productvariant.price
- H. facet on multiple properties of product (the parent)

Doing this with parent/child documents and `has_parent` in ES: **A-E + G** are possible.

However, how about **F** and **H**? I've looked into things as `_scope` for facets (although admittedly I don't grok the possibilities 100%) and all other stuff that comes to mind, but I don't see an obvious solution to show facets for product-properties and be able to sort by them in conjunction with `has_parent` .

I've tried other things (on paper)
 - has_child -> no luck need variant info returned
 - embedded docs (variant inside product) and return entire product with all variants. It just feels clunky. Moreover I'm pretty sure I can't facet/order on price that way.

Help much appreciated

Comment: note to self: probably possible when this is implemented: https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/issues/1383

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I banged my head on the wall for a long time trying to get a similar scheme working.  My scheme was a Product/Vendor relationship (single product sold by multiple vendors, potentially different descriptions/prices/availability).

Parent->Child mapping in ES just isn't very robust or easy to use right now.  Even if you get something working, you'll quickly run into edge-cases which are literally impossible because ES doesn't support it.

I think your best bet is to manage the parent->child mapping on your own and store the documents in their own index.  Products have an ID which is then stored in the ProductVariant documents as Product_ID.  This is actually how ES stores parent->child relationships internally anyway.

In practice, you query your "top level" index (Products), then perform a second query on your ProductVariant's index with a filter on the Product_ID field.

It's a little more hassle to maintain but sooo much more flexible.  At least until ES get's better Parent->Child capabilities

Comment: Agreed on the challenges! In your situation, how would you sort products on price (in the vendor-index?), since there's no way to limit the product-id's returned as its impossible to tell beforehand how they will get ordered by price right? So inother words your first query on Product needs to return all matching product-ids to look up the order in the second query, which imho seems pretty inefficient?

Comment: The least irritating way to do it is just to denormalize your data.  When vendor prices change, I update the vendor document, and then update the product document with a "Lowest-Price" field.  I can sort based on the lowest price field without having to do another query.  I come from a strong relational DBM background, so this takes some mental gymnastics to get used to.  Alternatively, you can sort by relevance, grab the top 100, query for prices, then resort (outside ES) the results based on prices.  Often people want "lowest price that is still relevant to my query", so it works fine.